# KiCad Simulation VSOURCE Triangle waveform

Tags: filter, simulation, spice, kicad, waveform

I want to simulate a second order active low-pass filter in KiCad, using the internal spice-based simulation tool. The input signal must be a triangle waveform of 30kHz and 0,5 V peak to peak, and the problem is I can't find any tutorial, on how to create a triangle waveform using the VSOURCE (Can't find the right settings). I know that I can build a triangle wave generator circuit using an op-amp, but I don't want to do that yet. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try the following settings:

[image: PulseSettings]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately I get the following error in the simulation: **Warning: v1: no DC value, transient time 0 value used**. I have the AC selected in the simulation settings. And also the bode plot shows no curves for the magnitude.

Comment: You will need to specify the DC value.  You didn't mention what you wanted that to be in your question, so I left it blank.

Comment: AC analysis doesn't make sense for triangular waves.